# Is there a way to auto-collect suns in Plants vs. Zombies for PC?

Tags: pc, plants-vs-zombies

I know that:

- There's a way to auto-collect coins/gold with Gold Magnet plant
- There a way to collect all suns with PlayStation version of PvZ by tilting.

**Is there a way (aside from clicking on each one) to auto-collect suns in PC version of the game?**

Comment: Oddly enough, you can have coins auto-collected, but not sun. `¬_¬`

Answer (score 5):

No, there is not. You could get a mod or hack for it, but strictly speaking no, there is not.

Comment: "could" as in I can write one, or could as in there exists one?

Comment: I've looked around and none exist, but also the files for pvz are encrypted so... Why do you need a mod in the first place?

Comment: I don't **need** a mode, but would like one. Getting CTS from clicking on suns is not an appealing idea :)

Comment: well it is designed to be a QTE game.

Comment: QTE = Quick Time Event (I hadn't heard the phrase before). But yes, it is the point of the game to click things, otherwise after the first 5 minutes of a level there is nothing to do...

Comment: if you want a slower tower defense game you can try bloons tower defense 5. it's a free flash game.